# Fedora 36 freezes intermittently

Tags: fedora, nvidia

I've recently moved to Fedora workstation 36 (from Fedora 32) and I'm having intermittent freezes that are annoying.

For instance, if I open a Nautilus window, and drag it, it will stop moving a few ms then continue. If I continue to move it, I will have this freeze every other few seconds.

I have a **NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]** graphic card, here's `lspci`:

```
$> lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

The akmod-nvidia drivers are installed (version *akmod-nvidia-3:515.65.01-1.fc36.x86_64*), and the NVidia driver is the 515.65.01. NVML is 11.515.65.01.

My OS is:

```
$> uname -a
Linux pc-cyril 5.18.16-200.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Aug 3 15:44:49 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Having `dmesg` open in realtime (`dmesg -wH`) doesn't show anything specific when the window freeze, but, from time to time, I have this error that appears:

```
[ 6sept. 13:50] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
[  +0,000010] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  +0,000003] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [144d:a804] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
[  +0,000003] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr
```

If I'm writing when it freezes, the keyboard stay with the press event and I have the same letter written multiple times.

If you think of any log output that could help this, please ask me and I'll share them!

**edit**: Launching Nautilus from the terminal doesn't show any errors when the drag freezes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running `nautilus` from a terminal and then check if any errors are printed there when the freeze happens. I wonder if this is similar to what I am seeing here: [Random freezes for chromium and electron-based apps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714450)

Comment: Just tried it. I got a freeze but nothing in the terminal :/

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try! Please add that to your question.

Comment: Hi, when you are in the Settings app under About, what do you see under Graphics? If it is anything but your NVIDIA card, it is because the driver was not correct loaded… cheers

Comment: Try here or here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148 https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules

Comment: @joshii_h I got the following : _NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 630 (KBL GT2)_. I believe both are recognized ?

Comment: @CyrilN. So I would suggest logging out and login without Wayland. As described here, if it resolves the lag, stay on x11: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/

Comment: @joshii_h I'm trying it and so far, it works great ! Didn't have any issues at all since I restarted under X11 ! You can write it as your answer (and maybe with how to set up permanently, as the doc explains). I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

So as we can see from the discussion:
NVIDIA and Wayland seem to have some issues still sometimes.

To resolve such issues we need to be sure that all Nvidia drivers are loaded correctly (within Fedora the best practice is to install it via RPM-Fusion) there are enough guides for this already.

But there are still some models, where the driver seems to have problems with Wayland, but not on X11.

It would be best to try out an X11 Session.
The Doc for how to do it would be here: [configuring Xorg as default gnome session](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/)

Thanks and Cheers